# Generating SSH key

Tags: git, github, git-bash, ssh-keys

I'm unable to create a .ssh directory or locate it while generating an SSH key

```
`
>Git Bash
>ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"
[]Generating public/private rsa key pair
[]Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa):
>Enter
[]Could not create directory '/c/Users/USER/.ssh' (No such file or directory)`
```

I've tried changing permissions but still not working.
YouTube videos aren't doing much help either

Edit(solution)
The problem was with my temp folder, I had to reset my PC to get it to the default state. The original code works without the need to create a .ssh folder manually.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem: "No such file or directory". Meaning that `/c/Users/USER/.ssh` doesn't exist. `ssh-keygen` will not make it for you, it will only create the file(s).

Comment: I've run the following command:
>$ mkdir .ssh
[]mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.ssh’: File exists

However, the problem still persists 
[]Saving key "/c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory

Comment: It might be related to using "git bash".

Comment: What does `ls -ld /c/Users/USER/.ssh` show? `touch /c/Users/USER/.ssh/test` ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could try setting the path where the key should be generated/put into and you are sure that you have permissions to do so with the help of the `-f` flag.

For example, setting it to `$HOME/id_rsa`

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com" -f "$HOME/id_rsa"
```